# I want to detect if the user clicks over the top left, the top right, the bottom left, or the bottom right part of the image.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a background image. I want to detect if the user clicks over the top left, the top right, the bottom left, or the bottom right part of the image. So, I imagined it divided in four quadrant, and I wrote this code:

```
$(document).ready(
    $('#Main').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();

        if((e.clientX-offset.left<($('#Main').width()*0.5))
            && (e.clientY - offset.top<($('.box').width()*0.5))){

            $('#Main').css("backgroundImage", "url(../images/img_2.png)");
    }
        if((e.clientX-offset.left>($('#Main').width()*0.5)) 
            && (e.clientY - offset.top<($('.box').width()*0.5))){

            $('#Main').css("backgroundImage", "url(../images/img_3.png)");
    }
        if((e.clientX-offset.left<($('#Main').width()*0.5))
            && (e.clientY - offset.top>($('.box').width()*0.5))){

            $('#Main').css("backgroundImage", "url(../images/img_4.png)");
    }
    if((e.clientX-offset.left>($('#Main').width()*0.5))
            && (e.clientY - offset.top>($('.box').width()*0.5))){

            $('#Main').css("backgroundImage", "url(../images/img_5.png)");
    }
    });
});
```

Sometimes it seems to work well, sometimes I click on a corner and the wrong image is loaded.

The html is very simple, I just have three divs, one inside the other.

Comment: You should add the full code with HTML, not just the jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, It was a stupid typo...I left ".box" instead of "#Main" because of a cut and paste!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend placing 4 empty divs on top of your main image - one in each corner.
Then all you need is add a "click" event to each of the 4 divs.

This is a much simpler solution and would be very easy to debug.

Comment: Agreed. This is what I was going to say. +1, speedy gonzalez